# Facebook long term access tokens using the Javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have obtained a short term access token using the simple Javascript SDK.
Now, to obtain the long term access token, I can use ajax or make a simple REST call in Javascript.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token,
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=' + appID + '&client_secret=' + appSecret + '&fb_exchange_token=' + short_term_access_token,
            success: function(response) { alert(reponse); }
        });
```

But is there an API with the Facebook Javascript SDK to obtain the long term access token in exchange for the short term one?

Comment: Why are you getting the long-lived token in client side code? There should be no reason to do this - it's better to fetch the long-lived token server-side, since you won't be able to make calls from the JS SDK without a user being logged in, and in that case you can silently and quickly get a new short-lived token

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have a small portal for the backend, from where I manage my users for my original app (different from the portal).
So, it doesnt matter, if I do it on the client side, because it wont be directly exposed to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the token to your server-side code to do the exchange token.
Don't put your app secret in client-side, it's not safe!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now have server side implementation